# cXML to java bindings issues

Tags: xsd, jaxb, xjc, cxml

Issue: Unable to create java classes from cXML.dtd using java xjc

version I am using is 1.2.032

command used :  xjc -dtd  cXML.dtd

Error : 
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] Property "Name" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve th
is conflict.

Issue 1 : Line number around 573


issue is with the "name" as its duplicate (element as well as attribute).

issue 2:
ShippingPaymentMethod,TermsOfDeliveryCode,TransportTerms uses "value" which is causing duplicate definations.

Solution as I understand==

I need custom  binding.xml .. I tried various ways but unable to create correct binding.xml  to solve this issue. once I have correct xml I can use following command to create generated classes.
xjc -b binding.xml -dtd  cXML.dtd

What I help I need

1. please provide correct binding.xml if possible
2. Is there any alternate way to generate java mappings for this cXML
3. Is there possibilities to have XSD and then have java mapping from XSD?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue Resolved by myself. did following steps.. may be useful for others

1. Renamed "name" element "ReturnData" in Cxml.dtd
2. Renamed "value" attr from TransportTerms,ShippingPaymentMethod,and TermsOfDeliveryCode in Cxml.dtd
3. Created java classes using
   xjc -dtd cXML.dtd

4.in Generated java classes changed xml annotation back to original.

So method names will be different but it will read and write correct XML.

Comment: cXML v 1.2.050
In addition I had to rename "serialNumber" of ATTLIST InvoiceDetailItemReference

Comment: Note: I would recommend to rename attribute elements by adding "Attribute", so it looks like nameAttribute, valueAttribute, serialNumberAttribute.

Answer (score 6):

FYI: you can also solve this with an external jax-b binding file that looks like this:

```
<xml-java-binding-schema xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
  <element name="ReturnData" type="class">
    <attribute name="name" property="nameAttribute"/>
  </element>
  <element name="ShippingPaymentMethod" type="class">
    <attribute name="value" property="valueAttribute"/>
  </element>
  <element name="TermsOfDeliveryCode" type="class">
    <attribute name="value" property="valueAttribute"/>
  </element>
  <element name="TransportTerms" type="class">
    <attribute name="value" property="valueAttribute"/>
  </element>
</xml-java-binding-schema>
```

The CXML spec is VERY annoying to generate JAX-B classes for because of their continued use of DTD over XML schema.  This is especially annoying if you want to use the other DTDs (Invoice, Catalog, Fulfill) as they each redefine all the common elements but use their own versions of the cxml.requests, cxml.messages, cxml.responses entities